# HTML5 <audio> end time

Tags: html, audio

In the code below I am playing a 60 second fragment from a 30 minute MP3 file (#t=60,180 - starts at 60 seconds, stops playing at 180 seconds). This uses the Media Fragment URI specification.

The HTML5 Audio player however show the progress bar with the full 30 minutes duration.

Three Questions:

1) Apart from hiding the progress bar completely, is there a way to only show the three minutes I want in  the progress bar. (Letting people fast forward & rewind but not go beyond the three minutes?)

2) Is there a way to only stream these three minutes rather than having to start loading in the entire MP3 file and wasting bandwidth?

3) If (1) is the only option, how do you hide the progress bar and also the total time length variable?

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>Test Player</figcaption>
    <audio
        controls
        src="/test.mp3#t=60,180 id="stream" style=" width:500px;>
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The only way you could potentially achieve something like this is by using Javascript. However, the "duration" attribute is [read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) and cannot be modified.
2. The best thing to do in this case would be to edit the audio file and cut the 3 minutes you want by using an [online tool](https://inettools.net/audio/cut-mp3-music-or-song-direct-online-free) or a program like [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).
3. You can hide the controls bar by simply omitting the 'controls' attribute from the audio tag. e.g.:

```
<audio  autoplay="" name="media"><source src="/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```